# A simpler version of $n$-th Leibniz Rule

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I am aware of the existence of the extension of Leibniz rule for the derivative of the product of functions, as well as other identities (e.g. https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/9/) for the $n$-th derivative of different operations between functions.

Yet my problem lies in this particular case: suppose I have this function
$$k(x) = \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
that is a common quotient, where both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials with real coefficients.

Faà Di Bruno's formula, together with Newton-Leibniz binomial extension, gives me the possibility of finding the $n$-th derivative of $k(x)$ through tedious and boring sums.

A professor though told us that in this particular case (that is, having a quotient between polynomials) we can avoid every sum, and with a simple trick we can find the wanted derivative.

For example he said we can find easily the second derivative of

$$\dfrac{x^2 + 10x}{3x^3 - 4x^2 + 2x - 11}$$

The problem is: how?? I really tried to calculate, writing down, using tricks like exponential writing or symbolic method, but nothing.

He added that we shall start trying with polynomials whose maximum degree is THREE to understand and gain the general strategy.

I searched on the web too but it seems something inexistent. Some help?

Comment: this might be be helpful for you: https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/find-the-nth-derivative-of-the-function-class-12-maths-cbse-6004e671df39ba6653b0033e

Comment: @StackpackedKar What? That is trivial. My problem is a bit more complicated